# Linux create mount point issue on ASUS RT-N56U router

Tags: linux, mount

On my RT-N56U router I'm trying to create a ext3 partition on an attached usb drive to store my media center data. The problem is I am unable to create to a mount point after creating the partition. When I run this command: mkdir /media/AiDisk_a1, it says it can't do it because file system is read only. This is probably because it's the in memory router OS. How can I mount my ext3 partition to /media/AiDisk_a1?

Also, is there a way in Linux to create a mount point without having write access to the main OS volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and create /media/AiDisk_a1 directory it won't work. Just build the ext3 partition and reconnect the drive  and it will auto-mount it.

Answer (score 1):

Command line on a router?!? Crazy talk!
What firmware are you running?

You can try using `sudo` at the beginning of the command, but if that fails, use `df -h` to find out what is mounted where. To find out what is mounted where and how it's mounted there use `sudo cat /etc/fstab`. Anything with an `ro` in its row is read only, likewise anything with a `rw` is read/write.

I'm assuming that it uses common linux commands. Good luck!

Comment: It's custom firmware, [here](http://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/) is the project site if that helps.

Comment: Did you get this working? What's the output if you do `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yep got it working. It works, just differently than I thought. I removed and re-added the drive, and it auto-mounted it to /tmp/mnt/sda1. So I unmounted it and manually re-mounted to /tmp/mnt/Content to have a cleaner Samba share name. What I need to figure out now, is how to have it auto-mount back to the same mount point after power outage.